# Raspberry Pi not showing that its working correctly

Tags: pi-3

I just bought my Raspberry Pi 3 today and it was working fine while I was trying to install the micro-SD card. After turning it off about an hour for some odd reason, it did not respond! It showed the red light, was getting enough power and everything, but all I got was a blank "no signal" screen on my monitor.

It was a Raspberry Pi 3 model B with a Canakit case. I may think it has something to do with the fact that I had just installed heat sinks. It worked fine before I installed them, but I'm pretty afraid that if I try to take them off it'll rip everything else off too.

Photos for a more clear view:
[image: raspberry pi case on] 
[image: raspberry pi case off]

Comment: In the future, please make an attempt at using proper grammar. If you don't put a reasonable amount of effort into asking your question, it's unlikely that people will care enough to put effort into answering.

Comment: Ok. I'm very sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

I once had the same problem, my micro SD card had snapped. It had caused a short and melted the card to the reader. So, you should check that your RPi's card reader and the card itself are fine.

Also, it could be that your heatsink(s) or thermal paste have shorted some contacts. ie. CPU'S contacts could be pretty easily shorted.

Comment: Actually I haven't installed the SD card yet, thats what i was going to do  after i would turn it on, but it wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, do I take the heatsinks off?

Comment: Your Raspberry Pi will not boot without  microSD card with compatible OS in it mounted. And maybe you should take the heatsinks off.

Comment: ok, here's what I'm working with if I'm not being that clear: An out-of-the-box canakit 32gb micro sd card raspberry pi 3 model b. I just setup the case, and put the SD card in. I gave it power and it worked for a while turning on with an error then staying on the "searching for sd card" screen. I was trying to make sure it could read the SD card or if it had some scratches on it. Then I turned it off (then added heat sinks) and back on, and it wouldn't come back on. just to be a bit more clear. And I'm going to take the heatsinks off and see what that does.